# Nested Update Query in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying update a range of records based on a join on the same table in SQLite3 using the application SQLiteman, I can't seem to get the right syntax and I have tried a number of methods. The latest iteration of the update query is below

```
Update
 workcodes wc2
Set
 wc2.SubCodeOf = wc1.ID
From
 workcodes wc1
 inner join
 workcodes wc2 on
 wc1.JemenaWC=wc2.WorkCode
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to try something like a sub-select:

```
UPDATE
    workcodes wc2
SET
    wc2.SubCodeOf = ( 
        SELECT wc1.ID 
        FROM workcodes wc1 
        WHERE wc1.JemenaWC = wc2.WorkCode )
```